# Межі застосування дієприкметників

Tags: дієприкметники

Не пам'ятаю звідки, але в моїй голові сидить теза про те, що в українській мові є якісь обмеження у застосуванні дієприкметників, суттєво відмінні від російської.

Це можна продемонструвати наступним прикладом:

- російською: *Вот человек, идущий на работу.*
- українською: *Ось людина, що йде на роботу.*

Те ж саме і в доконаному виді: *пришедший на работу* проти *що прийшла на роботу*.

Принаймні для дієслів недоконаного виду, така конструкція присутня і в англійській мові: *this is a person walking to work.*

Яке правило українського правопису регламентує такі випадки, та чи є більш стислі форми для передачі того ж змісту?

Comment: Є [отаке](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/diyeprykmetnyky). Але цей текст різні люди трактують по-різному. Та й згодні з ним, мабуть, теж не всі (хоча щодо останнього не впевнений).

Comment: [Ще тут](http://goo.gl/3FwB0G): В українській мові *не існує активних дієприкметників взагалі*. Існує деяка кількість *віддієслівних прикметників*, що втратили дієслівні ознаки (час і вид) і означають уже не дію, як дієприкметники, а сталу властивість когось чи чогось. Наприклад, «нападаючий злочинець» — неправильно, а «нападаючий» як роль у футбольній команді — правильно.

Comment: @bytebuster, це цікаво, але, на жаль, це wiki, написана невідомо наскільки обізнаною людиною — хоч і на основі двох серйозних джерел: Б. Антоненко-Давидович «Як ми говоримо» і Олена Курило «Уваги до сучасної української літературної мови». Посилання на перше джерело я вже давав, тож тепер лишається додати посилання на [друге](http://kurylo.wikidot.com/1-prykmetnyky-diieslivnoho-pokhodzhennia).

Comment: @Sasha, саме так. Тому я і не став робити із цього відповідь. Бо відповідь не має базуватися на єдиному джерелі інформації. Але запостив як коментар на випадок, якщо хтось знається на проблемі краще і зможе використати наведену інформацію (або спростувати її). А потім флагне мені на коментарі, коли він більше не буде потрібним, щоб я видалив.

Comment: @bytebuster, зорієнтуйте, будь ласка, де встановлені вимоги щодо посилань на більше ніж одне джерело інформації у відповіді?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, забув :) додати головне: **у моєму суб'єктивному розумінні**, відповідь не має ґрунтуватися виключно на єдиному джерелі, бо на одне джерело найлегше знайти опонента (досить поважного), який будь-яку теорію може оскаржити. Наприклад, у мене давно [лежить матеріал](https://bytebuster.dreamwidth.org/9117106.html) на запитання+власну відповідь на одну спірну тему, де словник Дмитра Яворницького суперечить самому Максу Фасмеру, великому і могутньому. І я упевнений, що якщо я не надам **більше джерел**, то цей допис викличе бурю заперечень.

Comment: @bytebuster, зрозуміла - самі собі встановлюємо обмеження) щодо Вашого матеріалу за посиланням, то думаю, він викличе бурю заперечень і емоцій і з інших причин: не на часі, так би мовити) та й, мабуть, не на цьому ресурсі)

Answer (score 6):

Професор Ющук І.П., [Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf) (2012).

> **§ 87. Дієприкметник як форма дієслова**
>
> Дієприкметник, як уже свідчить його назва, має ознаки і дієслова, і
>   прикметника. Відповідає на питання *який*?
>
> Як форма дієслова він називає дію, буває **доконаного**
>   (*позеленілий*) або
>   **недоконаного** (*зеленіючий*) виду, має ознаку **перехідності** (*побілений*) і **неперехідності** (*побілілий*). З іншого боку,
>   дієприкметник, як і прикметник, називає **ознаку предмета** (*достигле
>   яблуко*), **змінюється за родами, числами й відмінками** (*достиглий,
>   достигле, достиглі, достиглих*).
>
> **Дієприкметники бувають активні і пасивні.**
>
> **Активний дієприкметник** називає ознаку предмета, зумовлену дією того самого предмета: в*огнище погасло — погасле вогнище; вогнище
>   згасає — згасаюче вогнище*.
>
> **Пасивний дієприкметник** називає ознаку предмета, зумовлену дією іншого предмета: *хтось погасив вогнище — погашене вогнище*. Крім
>   того, пасивні дієприкметники можуть називати ознаку предмета,
>   зумовлену зворотною дією того самого предмета: *хлопець умився —
>   умитий хлопець; дівчина збентежилася — збентежена дівчина*.
>
> Час у дієприкметниках не визначається. Частки (постфікса) -ся в
>   дієприкметниках не буває: відірвався — відірваний, згорбився —
>   згорблений
>
> Пасивні дієприкметники короткої форми не мають.
>
> Усі дієприкметники відмінюються, як прикметники твердої групи
>
> **§ 88. Творення і вживання активних дієприкметників**
>
> Активні дієприкметники творяться лише від неперехідних дієслів.
>
> Активні дієприкметники бувають доконаного і недоконаного виду.
>
> 1. **Активні дієприкметники доконаного виду** творяться, як і минулий час, від основи неозначеної форми дієслова доконаного виду **за
>      допомогою суфікса `-л(ий)`**: посиві(ти)—*посивілий*, підупа(сти) —
>      *підупалий*, зів’я(нути)—
>      *зів’ялий*.
>
> Суфікси **`-ш(ий`**), **`-вш(ий)`**, **`-вш(ийся)`** в українській
>   мові для творення дієприкметників **не використовуються**: не
>   “посинівший”, а *посинілий*; не “висохший”, а *висохлий*; не
>   “розчервонівшийся”, а *розчервонілий*.
>
> 2. **Активні дієприкметники недоконаного виду** творяться від основи теперішнього часу дієслова за допомогою суфікса **`-уч(ий)`** для І
>      дієвідміни і **`-ач(ий)`** для II дієвідміни. Для цього досить
>      дієслово поставити в 3-й особі множини теперішнього часу (що роблять?
>      ) і -ть замінити на -ч(ий): несуть — *несучий*, радіють — *радіючий*,
>      лежать — *лежачий*, скриплять —
>      *скриплячий*.
> 3. **Активні дієприкметники недоконаного виду (на -учий, -ачий) вживаються рідко, і то без залежних слів:** Не бійся гостя *сидячого*,
>      а бійся
>      *стоячого* (Нар. творчість). *Умираючий* промінь сонця падає на березу, кривавить білу кору (А.Шиян). Здалеку долітають *завмираючі*
>      гуки музики (І.Нечуй-Левицький). *Нудьгуючими* очима дивився він на
>      село (З.Тулуб).
>
> **Але як неприродні, штучні сприймаються ті самі дієприкметники, коли їх вжито із залежними словами**: Не бійся гостя, *сидячого за столом*.
>   Поволі
>   *вмираючий* на заході *промінь* сонця кривавить білу кору берези. Здалеку долітають *завмираючі* в ранковій тиші *гуки* музики.
>   *Нудьгуючими* від пересичення *очима* дивився він на село.
>
> **У такому разі їх слід замінити**:
>
> а) **підрядним означальним реченням**: Не бійся гостя, *що сидить за
>   столом*;
>
> б) **дієприслівником**: Промінь сонця, *поволі вмираючи на заході*,
>   кривавить білу кору берези;
>
> в) **способовою формою дієслова**: Здалеку долітають гуки музики й
>   *завмирають у ранковій тиші*;
>
> г) **пасивним дієприкметником**: *Знудженими від пересичення очима*
>   дивився він на село.
>
> **Частіше активні дієприкметники недоконаного виду використовуються в термінологічних словосполученнях**: *блукаючий нерв, крокуючий
>   екскаватор, несуча поверхня крила, ведуче колесо, резонуюча камера,
>   ріжучий диск, діючий вулкан, тонізуючі речовини*.
>
> **Але й тут їх намагаються по можливості уникнути**.
>
> Наприклад, замість “*оточуюче середовище*” тепер кажуть: ***навколишнє
>   середовище, довкілля, оточення***; замість “*ріжучий інструмент*” —
>   ***різальний інструмент***; замість “*спрямовуюча рейка*” — ***напрямна рейка***; замість “*узагальнююче слово*” — ***узагальнювальне слово***; замість “*уточнюючий член речення*” — ***уточнювальний член речення*** тощо.