# Чи правильно вживати слово "існуючий"?

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, from-russian, калька, дієприкметники

Прочитала, що краще не вживати слово "існуючий", так як це калька з російської від "существующий". Але в словниках це слово є - то чи можна його вживати?

[Всесвітній словник української мови](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9)

> *ІСНУ́ЮЧИЙ* (перев. щодо абстрактних понять - який існує або існував).

[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/isnujuchyj)

> *ІСНУ́ЮЧИЙ*, а, е. Дієпр. акт. теп. ч. до існувати 1. Треба поліпшити існуючу систему контролю якості (Радянська Україна, 27.VIII 1959, 2).

[Onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/)

> Замініть *існуючий* на один з варіантів: наявний, нинішній, сучасний, — або підрядне речення.

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1262/

Comment: А "неіснуючий" тоді як ви пропонуєте перекласти?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия *ви́гаданий, нереа́льний, уявле́нний, химе́рний, живи́й лише́ у снах, уя́вний, незафіксо́ваний, відсу́тній, (у природі) невідо́мий, фраз. ме́ртвий ни́ні.*

Answer (score 8):

Більшість мовознавців, зокрема Олена Курило, Борис Антоненко-Давидович, Юрій Шевельов, Олександр Пономарів, Святослав Караванський, радили й радять уникати активних дієприкметників на *-ачий*, *-учий*, оскільки вони є невластивими українській мові. Варіанти на різні випадки передачі змісту вислову пропонуються [тут](//ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieprukmetnuku-iz-zakinchennyamu-achuj,-yachuj,-uchuj,-yuchuj-vzhuvatu-chu-ni).
На блодзі [Філологічні викрутаси](http://filvukrytas.blogspot.com.tr/p/blog-page_15.html?view=timeslide) наведено кілька відповідників до дієприкметника *існуючий*:

> НЕПРАВИЛЬНО — ПРАВИЛЬНО
>
> *існуюче* законодавство — *чинне* законодавство
> *існуючі* теориторії — *наявні* теорії
> *існуючий* порядок — *заведений* порядок
> *існуючі* ціни — *теперішні* ціни
> *існуючі* кордони — *сучасні* кордони
> *існуючі* досі проблеми — *наявні* проблеми

Отже, нема конечної потреби послуговуватися словом *існуючий*, краще замінити його на більш природнє для української мови.

Answer (score 2):

#### Далі наведені цікаві цитати про активні дієприкметники з різних джерел.

Літ.: Кучеренко І. К. Грамат. характеристика дієприкметника і його місце в системі частин мови. «Мовознавство», 1967, № 4; Русанівський В. М. Структура укр. дієслова. К., 1971; Гнатюк Г. М. Дієприкметник у сучас. укр. літ. мові. К., 1982.

Г. М. Гнатюк.

> Д. на -чий поширені мало, тому що народнорозм. мова, яка лягла в
>   основу сучас. укр. літ. мови, майже не знала їх (як книжних форм
>   давньорус. походження). В сучас. мові вони дещо активізувалися,
>   зокрема у зв’язку з творенням н.-т. термінів (крокуючий екскаватор,
>   блукаючий нерв).

ІСТОРІЯ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ ЛІТЕРАТУРНОЇ МОВИ, Віталій РУСАНІВСЬКИЙ, 2001

> Окремо слід зупинитися на такій спірній формі, як активні
>   дієприкметники теперішнього часу. Власне, закономірність їх уживання в
>   українській літературній мові по-справжньому аргументованих заперечень
>   ні в кого й не викликала, проте помічалося прагнення уникати їх як не
>   народної, а запозиченої з староукраїнської мови форми. До того ж майже
>   не засвідчувались — принаймні на Східній Україні — дієприкметникові
>   звороти з цими формами. В. Винниченко ставився до активних
>   дієприкметників теперішнього часу аж надто толерантно. Поряд із
>   словосполученнями, в яких дієприкметники вживалися переважно в
>   атрибутивному значенні, він допускав і дієприкметникові звороти.
>   Наприклад: дрижача рука, /284/ прохаючий голос, розуміюча посмішка
>   («Краса і сила»), блукаючі очі («З споминів»), Чого при людях вона з
>   ним така близька, така щось знаюча, патякуюча, голубляча («Соняшна
>   машина»).

Енциклопедія українознавства. Словникова частина (ЕУ-II). — Париж, Нью-Йорк, 1973. — Т. 7. — С. 2571-2583.

> У словотворі термінологізмів поширено застосування звичніших у
>   російщині суфіксів: -чик/-щик (пікіровщик — пікувальник), -тель
>   (зачинатель — започаткувач) -ка (для назв дії: закльопка —
>   заклепування), -о/е-видний (конусовидний — стіжкуватий),
>   дієприкметники активні на -щий, а(ю)чий, -уючий, -вший (трудящий,
>   служачий — працівник, співчуваючий — співчутливий, заіснувавший —
>   заіснувалий, насталий; перемігший — переможний) й пасивний на -мий
>   (любимий усіма — люблений), -ичати (важничати — вдавати важного), як і
>   словоскладення ц.-слов. типу (злосмрадний — відразливий, горе-вчений —
>   партач) і запозичення чи кальки (дітище — духова дитина, відщепенець —
>   апостат, перекинчик). Всякі тенденції до унезалежнення укр. літ. мови
>   від рос., як і раніші пуристичні намагання очистити її від калькових
>   канцеляризмів, проголошено бездискусійно «укр. буржуазним
>   націоналізмом та фашизмом у мові», а дотичних мовознавців репресовано.

Енциклопедія українознавства. Загальна частина (ЕУ-I). — Мюнхен, Нью-Йорк, 1949-52. — 1230 с.

> Дієприкметники на -чий, -ший, -мий зникли; з деяких із них стали
>   прикметники, пасивні дієприкметники на -ний, -тий збереглися. З
>   колишніх активних дієприкметників розвинулися незмінні дієприслівники
>   теперішнього й минулого часу: пізнаючи, походивши. Крім того, з
>   пасивного дієприкметника витворилася безособова форма на -но, -то
>   (зроблено, вжито).

ПАМВО БЕРИНДА І ЙОГО „ЛЕКСІКОНЪ СЛАВЕНОРΩССКЇЙ И ИМЕНЪ ТЛЪКОВАНЇЄ“, Василь Німчук

> Багато в словнику активних дієприкметників на -чїй, а також утворень
>   на -лый. Наприклад: маючїй (88); перебираючі(й) (105); преходАчую
>   (118); непсуючїйсА (144); чуючимъ (258); полюючїи а(б)[о] чигаючїи,
>   стерегучїи (354); застарЂлый (69); ωпилый (369); ωброслы(й) (112);
>   згустЂлый, зсЂлы(й) (274).

Ідіотизми сталінської ярижки у державній мові України. Святослав Караванський. 2016

> Існуючий.
>   - Сущий, наявний, сучас-, теперішній, живий, не мёрт-, з-й
>   існувати, (у світі) подибува-, відомий, (закон) наш, (- права)
>   зафіксований.
>
> - Усі існуючі істоти. Усі сущі істоти.
> - Існуючий у природі. Наявний у природі.
> - Існуючий порядок. Сучасний порядок.
> - Існуючі закони. Наші закони.
> - Існуючий у воді. 3-й жити у воді.
> - Існуючий в уяві мрійників. Існуючи в уяві мрійників.
>
> Подекуди форму існуючий можна замінити дієприкметником минулого часу:
>
> - Існуючий спосіб. Уживаний спосіб.
> - Існуючий міф. Поширений міф.
> - Існуючий у світі. Подйбуваний у світі.
> - Існуюче право. Узаконене право,

Звідки пішла єсть московська мова або шила в мішку не сховаєш. Святослав Караванський. 2012.

> !!! + ім = Складне слово — Його значення — Московська модель
>
> - Гуляй! + поле = гулайполе — поле, що гуляє — гуляюче поле
> - Підопри! + гора = підопригора — що, хто підпира гору — підпираючий гору
> - Коли! + вушко = коливушко — що, хто коле вушко — колючий вушко
> - Пали! + копа = паликопа — що, хто палить копи — палячий копи
> - Крути! + вус = крути вус — що, хто крутить вуса — крутячий вуса

#### Я теж маю слово

Существующий — той, що існує. Сущий — застаріле.

*Це все що я знайшов з пояснення. Джерела не авторитетні, тому й не вказував. Можете знайти більше — напишіть, будь ласка.*

Зі словника я б підібрав слово слово дійсний.

Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. Бусел. 2005 року.

> Дійсний — 1. Який насправді існує або існував; реальний. 2. ...

#### То чи правильно вживати слово існуючий?

На це запитання відповість Українська граматика 2019 року.

> § 119. Дієприкметник
>
> В українській мові розмежовують:
>
> 1. Дієприкметники активного стану:
>
>    1). теперішнього часу на -чий (-а, -е) (вживані переважно в значенні прикметників та іменників): квіту́чий, живу́чий, лежа́чий, стоя́чий;
>
>    2). минулого часу на -лий (-а, -е): зжо́вклий, нави́слий, осі́лий, почорні́лий.

Comment: Тобто висновок такий, що формально дозволено, але фактично нерекомендовано, — я правильно зрозумів?

Comment: @Sasha Залежить від змісту.

Comment: А як саме залежить від вмісту (бо це справді це неочевидно з Вашої відповіді; хоч влна мені дуже подобається)?

Answer (score 1):

Як я зрозумів, це вживання слова "існуючий" є досить спірне. Ось, що я прочитав на сайті [ar25](https://www.ar25.org/article/osoblyvosti-vzhyvannya-diyeprykmetnykiv.html):

> Як відомо, дієприкметники – це форма дієслова, яка означає ознаку
>   предмета за дією або станом і відповідає на питання який? яка? які? За
>   значенням вони поділяються на активні і пасивні. Найбільш суперечливим
>   є функціонування в українській мові активних дієприкметників. Деякі
>   мовознавці, І. Вихованець, К. Горденська, вважають, що вони чужі для
>   нашої мови. Проте, проаналізувавши творчість наших класиків і усну
>   народну творчість, ми переконуємось, що такі дієприкметники все-таки
>   властиві українській мові. Їх використовували І. Нечуй-Левицький, І.
>   Франко, Л. Українка, Т. Шевченко й ін. Наприклад:
>   “**Прислуговуючі** наймички та молодиці насилу постягали страви”. (І.
>   Нечуй-Левицький). “До праці, молоді приятелі, до інтенсивної,
>   **невсипущої** праці над собою самими”.(І. Франко). “І в неволі познає
>   рай, познає волю і **всетворящую** любов”. (Т. Шевченко).

І також там є інформація про слово "існуючий":

> Слід пам’ятати, що такий активний дієприкметник, як існуючий, має
>   також багато синонімічних відповідників. Тому **слово “існуючий” треба
>   вживати у випадку, коли йдеться про животіння чогось, неактивне,
>   бездіяльне існування**. Наприклад: “Існуючий уряд” , коли йдеться про
>   його бездіяльність, яловість.
>
> В інших випадках вживаємо відповідники: сущий, є, наявний, чинний,
>   оскільки вони стилістично є виразнішими. До прикладу:
>
> **Чинні закони**, **наявні у природі**, **сущий світ**.

Однак, слід враховувати, що це не думка мовознавця (автора статті звати Оксана Лутчин), тому не можна довіряти такій інформації на всі 100% (хоч деякі свої думки вона підтверджує прикладами із творів українських авторів).

На [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B7_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97) ми можемо знайти сторінку "Список помилок перекладу з російської", де пише, що переклад слова "существующий" на українську "існуючий" - є невірним. Потрібно вживати "**нинішній**", "**сучасний**", "**наявний**". Пояснення:

> Активні дієприкметники на -юч- українській мові не властиві

На сайті [Правильно-неправильно](http://nepravylno-pravylno.wikidot.com/all) бачимо ще такі варіанти заміни:

Фактично існуючі відносини - **Реальні** відносини

Порушення існуючих законів - Порушення **чинних** законів

Сайт [200 балів](https://www.200baliv.com/yak-pravylno-bazhayuchyj-chy-ohochyj-zaviduyuchyj-chy-zaviduvach-aktyvni-dijeprykmetnyky-v-ukrajinskij-movi/) дає ще більше прикладів:

існуючий план роботи – **даний** план роботи

існуючі кордони – **сучасні** кордони

існуючі методи – **наявні** методи

Ще додам приклад такої заміни - "існуючі досі проблеми" - "[проблеми, що досі є (наявні)](https://web.posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/icgn/radomska_ukr_mova/8.htm)".