# "Оточуючий" чи "навколишній" - різниця між словами

Tags: переклад, росіянізм, дієприкметники

Допоможіть розібратися з вживанням цих слів: в першому джерелі вказано, що слова мають різний сенс, в другому - радять не вживати це слово, а от в Словнику це слово є.

[Перше джерело](https://eukraina.com/news/vchimo_ukrajinsku_movu_navkolishnij_otochujuchij/2010-04-18-11173)

> Значення слів *оточуючий* і *навколишній* дуже близькі, проте є випадки, коли їх слід розрізняти. Зокрема, *навколишній* має ширшу сполучуваність. Наприклад, «навколишні люди, села, будинки, звуки, навколишня дійсність». У формі середнього роду, поєднуючись із займенником «все», слово навколишнє вживається як іменник. Цей іменник стосується всього, крім людей. 
>   Дієприкметник *оточуючий* у множині також може використовуватись як іменник. У таких випадках він стосується тільки людей. 
>   Синонімом до слова *оточуючі* може виступати спільнокореневий іменник оточення.

[Onlinecorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8F/)

> Вживання дієприкметників активного стану з -уч-, -юч- не рекомендовано нормами сучасної української мови. Замініть *оточуючий* на один з варіантів: навколишній, довколишній, навкружний; той, що оточує; присутні, близькі, прибічники; (світ) довкілля; (люди) оточення.

[Академічний тлумачний словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/otochujuchyj)

> *ОТО́ЧУЮЧИЙ*, а, е, рідко. Дієпр. акт. теп. ч. до оточувати. Параскіца хрестилась та била поклони, а на обличчях оточуючої її жіноти малювався кислий вираз (Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 277); Око від перевтоми закривається. Хворий втрачає контакт з оточуючим світом (Ірина Вільде, Сестри.., 1958, 99).

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1262/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Словник пише "Оточуючий - Дієпр. акт. теп. ч. до оточувати". Воно так і є. Якщо Ірині Вільде як совєцькій письменниці не варто йняти віри, то тексти Михайла Коцюбинського є чи не основою класичної літературної мови. Як на мене, у нього в цитованому тексті "оточуючий" вжито як годиться - щодо людей, які оточили іншу людину. Я б радив сміливо ігнорувати поради сучасних, а насправді совєцьких академіків і філологів (школа філології в нас залишилася вся та сама, сталінська, гончарівська - Єфремова й побратимів, як відомо, розстріляли або згубили зо світу в інші способи).

Слово "довколишній", яке походить від "довкола", зазвичай використовується щодо будівель, конструкцій, не людських об'єктів (буквальний переклад російською - "окольньій"). Навіть коли згадаємо слово "довкілля", то йдеться саме про "environment" - простір і не-людські об'єкти в ньому навколо суб'єкта (який може бути людиною або не людиною). До речі, якщо вбити "довколишній" у [пошук в r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on), то побачимо способи використання саме в такому контексті. 
Тому, як на мене, в цитатованому тексті Вільде ліпше вжити "Хворий втрачає контакт з навколишнім світом". 
Тобто зі світом, який навколо, а не який оточує - світ як такий не може оточити, це може зробити лише людина (як і точитися, точити тощо). І коли "оточуючий" вживається щодо конструкцій, простору, не-людей, то це калька з російської "окружающий мир", де "о**круж**ающий" якраз має спільний корінь з "дов**кола**".

Сподіваюсь, що допоміг розібратися, а ще ліпше - відчути.