# Активні дієприкметники (благаючий погляд)

Tags: синоніми, дієприкметники

Як можна замінити вираз?

```
Вона подивилася на мене благаючим поглядом
```

Наскільки я знаю, активні дієприкметники подібного роду непритаманні українській мові.

Мені потрібно знайти заміну в даному **конкретному випадку**
Тобто, у цій фразі. Спроба фразеологічної заміни типу "собачим поглядом" не дуже проходить.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Межі застосування дієприкметників](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/%d0%9c%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%96-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d1%96%d1%94%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%96%d0%b2)

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine, я все знаю. Річ в тім, що я не можу підібрати слово згідно з цими правилами в даному конкретному прикладі.

Comment: А чим не підходить ось це, що вказано у відповіді? *«У такому разі їх слід замінити: а) підрядним означальним реченням»* — у даному випадку, *поглядом, що благає* або *поглядом, повним благання*.

Comment: Таки да, "поглядом, сповненим благання" підходить.

Answer (score 2):

Випадково знайшов сторінку, де пані Марія описує [п'ять способів заміни активних дієприкметників](https://buki.com.ua/blogs/vzhyvannya-aktyvnykh-diyeprykmetnykiv-v-ukrayinskiy-movi/):

> #### **1 спосіб. Замінити прикметником:**
>
> бажаючі складати ЗНО – охочі складати ЗНО
> біжуча вода – проточна вода
> біжучий рядок – рухомий рядок
> блукаючий сюжет – мандрівний сюжет
> ведуча організація – провідна організація
> виконуючий обов’язки – виконувач обов’язків
> виступаючий – доповідач
> віруючий – вірянин
> вміщуючий залізо – багатий на залізо, залізовмісний
> відстаючий учень – відсталий учень
> водоплаваючі птахи – водоплавні птахи
> ворогуючі сторони – ворожі сторони
> вражаючі результати – разючі результати
> гальмуючий шлях – гальмівний шлях
> діюча особа – дійова особа
> діючий вулкан – активний вулкан
> діючий закон – чинний закон
> домінуючий мотив – домінантний мотив
> друкуючий пристрій – друкувальний пристрій
> думаюча, мисляча людина – вдумлива людина
> енергозберігаючі лампи – лампи енергозбереження
> жарознижуючий засіб – жарознижувальний засіб
> завідуючий кафедрою – завідувач кафедри
> захоплюючі краєвиди – захопливі, привабливі, звабливі, принадні краєвиди
> зволожуючий крем – зволожувальний крем
> зворушуюча зустріч – зворушлива зустріч
> знаюча людина – тямуща, компетентна, обізнана людина
> зникаючі види – напівзниклі види
> життєстверджуючий настрій – життєствердний настрій
> інакомислячий – інакодумець
> існуючі кордони – сучасні кордони
> існуючі методи – наявні методи
> координуючий центр – координаційний центр
> комплектуючі деталі – деталі для комплектування
> миючі засоби – мийні засоби або засоби для миття
> наступаюче свято – прийдешнє свято
> обезболюючий засіб – знеболювальний засіб
> оточуюче середовище – навколишнє середовище, довкілля
> пануюча ідея – панівна ідея
> переконуючий доказ – переконливий доказ
> підростаюче покоління – молоде покоління
> правляча еліта – керівна еліта
> приваблююча пропозиція – приваблива пропозиція
> уточнюючі члени речення – уточнювальні члени речення
> хвилюючі слова – зворушливі слова
> спляча красуня – приспана красуня
>
> #### **2 спосіб. Замінити іменником:**
>
> акомпануючий – акомпаніатор
> виступаючий – доповідач, лектор, промовець
> відпочиваючий – відпочивальник
> віруючий – вірянин
> головуючий – голова
> завідуючий кафедрою – завідувач кафедри
> керуючий – керівник
> контролюючий – контролер
> оточуюче середовище – довкілля
> оточуючі люди – оточення
> подорожуючий – подорожній і мандрівник
> поступаючий – вступник
> потопаючий – потопельник
> початкуючий – початківець
> працюючий – працівник
>
> #### **3 спосіб. Замінити іменником-прикладкою:**
>
> збираюча лінза – лінза-збирач
> лідируюча команда – команда-лідер
> початкуючий поет – поет-початківець
>
> #### **4 спосіб. Замінити словосполученням:**
>
> люблячий тебе – з любов’ю до тебе
> перебуваючий на ремонті – поставлений на ремонт
> стоячі місця – місця для стояння
> сидячі місця – місця для сидіння
>
> #### **5 спосіб. І, нарешті, якщо ніщо попереднє не підходить, замінити конструкцією «що…», «який…»:**
>
> знаючий фізику – що знає фізику
> перебуваючий у відрядженні – що перебуває у відрядженні
> перебуваючий за кордоном – що перебуває за кордоном
> плачучий – який плаче, у сльозах
> працюючий у великій компанії - що працює у великій компанії
> подорожуючий – який подорожує.

Answer (score 1):

> Вона подивилася на мене **благальним** поглядом

*Благальний* - це той, що призначений для *благання*. Тобто вона використала погляд за допомогою якого вона благала. Як от *рятувальний* човен створений для *рятування*.

> 10. [ОСНОВА ДІЄСЛОВА + СУФІКС –(УВ)АЛЬН(ИЙ).](https://science.lpnu.ua/uk/terminologiya/vsi-vypusky/visnyk-no-733-2012/sufiksaciya-yak-produktyvnyy-sposib-tvorennya) Дериват *-альн* розповсюджений у прикметникових номінаціях зі значенням активної дії або вказує на призначення пристроїв або інструментів: *постачальний, приймальний, понижувальний, обслуговувальний, перетворювальний, освітлювальний, компенсувальний, підіймальний, зварювальний, регулювальний, підсилювальний, складальний.*

Не знаю, правда, чи можна розглядати погляд як пристрій чи інструмент, але ж є і рятувальник, якого теж важко розглядати як пристрій чи інструмент, але ж тут теж призначення очевидне.

Взагалі, я намагаюсь вживати цей суфікс лише для вказання на призначення.